# Waiting for DDos protection process to finish, then load image using Glide

Tags: java, android, android-glide, ddos

I'm trying to load an image from URL, e.g. https://freepikpsd.com/file/2021/03/vector-college-icon-png-.png with Glide.

Due to DDos protection process, the image is not loaded by Glide.

```
Glide.with(context)
     .asBitmap()
     .load("https://freepikpsd.com/file/2021/03/vector-college-icon-png-.png")
     .into(holder.imageView);
```

Is there any way to make glide wait till the DDoS process finishes, then load the image?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Cloudscraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudscraper) to "bypass" cloudflares JS Challenge. You won't succeed through the captcha tho. If this is your site make an Firewall rule that allows this PATH and cache it. If the picture is cached by cloudflare no js challenge / Captcha will be needed to protect you against DDoS attacks. No Traffic will come to the backend except you disable cache (Dev mode etc.)